# The constraint entry 'inboundHttpMethod' must have a string value or be of a type which implements 'IHttpRouteConstraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to implement attribute routing, but getting following error.

> The constraint entry 'inboundHttpMethod' on the route with route
>   template 'authenticate' must have a string value or be of a type which
>   implements 'IHttpRouteConstraint

I already added the line of code in Global.asax,

```
    AttributeRoutingHttpConfig.RegisterRoutes(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes);
```

and the below code in AttributeRoutingHttpConfig.cs,

```
routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(cfig =>
            {
                cfig.UseLowercaseRoutes = true;
                cfig.AutoGenerateRouteNames = true;
                cfig.AddRoutesFromAssemblyOf<AuthenticateController>();
                cfig.InMemory = true;
            });
```

Anyone know about the issue, actually I am new to c#.

Comment: The `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` extension method does not have the signature you provided. Are you sure you are using the correct NuGet packages (Web API 2)?

Comment: yes, there are no syntax errors.

Comment: As I stated, [`MapHttpAttributeRoutes` does not accept any kind of lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dn479134%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), I do not believe you are using Web API 2 native attribute routing. Please double check your NuGet Packages. Can you add the using statements of your `AttributeRoutingHttpConfig.cs` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong packages.

From what I can see you are trying to implement attribute routing using [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting.WebApi) (old and no longer supported).

This package supports *Web API v1* (assembly version 4.*), and not *Web API 2* (assembly version 5.*).

Web API 2 support for attribute routing is native. This tutorial may help you implementing such a feature: [Attribute Routing in Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Here it is a small example:

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/myexample")]
public MyController : ApiController {
    [Route("foo")]
    public string GetFoo()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

This action may be reached at the following endpoint: `http://myhost/v1/myexample/foo`.

Remember to register them in your `WebApiConfig.cs` file:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Other Web API configuration
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Federico, I was following someone blog in web api 2 project. Now its working fine, I removed all external packages and code.